# Python aren't able to use selenium's webdriver module. What should i do?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\puton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\puton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\puton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\puton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\puton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

This is my error if you are not able to help me please do not answer ty.

Comment: Post your code. it seems you missed setting chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

driver = webdriver.Chrome('//path//to//chromedriver') 
use // backslashes  n try